# DotNetNuke URL Rewriting With HTTPS Not Working

Tags: .net, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

I am using DotNetNuke v05.05.00(653) , and I've activated the Friendly URL from the host settings.  Everything about rewriting is just working like a charm, except when I use the HTTPS protocol, it gives me the 404 error.

It seems like it's a url-rewriting issue with the HTTPS protocol, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would double check the bindings in IIS.

Comment: Another thing apart from @notandy has pointed is to look at https settings at host settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was an issue introduced in 5.5.0, it was resolved with the 5.5.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

You  don't have to do anything special to Dotnetnuke to have it work over HTTPS.  If you have fiddled with the site settings regarding enforcing https that may cause it but this is most likely do to IIS.

In IIS make sure you have your host headers / bindings configured correctly.  You should have your HTTP on 80 and HTTPS on port 443.  Also confirm you have an IP set when using HTTPS in IIS and you will also need to set up a secure certificate on the server. HTTPS is not just inherent.

Make sure the domain you are using is set in Site Settings which is also in the PortalAlias table in your SQL Server database.

99% sure that this is not a friendly URL issue, or anything to do with DNN.